# Connecting multiple sql users to one database with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

Hello i am a beginner in C# winform,
I have to connect multiple users (400 different users) through a login form ( textbox : name - password) to a single sql database with Winform C#, all users are sql users created in the database and have roles like users or admin.
I have been looking for an easy way of doing this with entity framework but couldn't find anyhting.. anyone has an idea how this can be done ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read the site's help on how to ask questions. This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Does every user need their own login to the database?

If this is true you would need to write a special connection string, something like below:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=ServerName;" +
    "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
    "User id=" + UserName + ";"
    "Password=" + Password + ";";
 conn.Open();
```

Put this in a class that accepts the username and password.

Full example:

```
class myConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User id=" + UserName + ";Password=" + Password + ";";
        SQlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User credentials are specified in the connection string, so you need to build a connection string with the data provided by the user in the login form.

```
var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

// Set the properties for the data source.
sqlBuilder.DataSource = "ServerName";
sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "DatabaseName";

sqlBuilder.UserID = "USERNAME";
sqlBuilder.Password = "PASSWORD";

sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

// Build the SqlConnection connection string.
string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

// Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

//Set the provider name.
entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

// Set the provider-specific connection string.
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;
```

And then use this connection string to initialize your  `DbContext`

```
var context = new DbContext(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
```